# Assigning colors to categories in R

Tags: r, colors, points

I am trying to assign two colors to two categories in my data.  They are two different species.  I would like one species to be blue and the other red.  If I leave it at col=species, it makes them black and red.  I changed it to col=c("red","blue",[species]) and it only shows the blue points, doesn't even include the other species in it.

> plot(pronotum,weight,pch=16,col=c("red","blue",[species]))

I am okay with leaving it black and red if I ultimately can't figure it out, it's mostly just an annoyance for me at this point.  I have to figure it out!

Thanks!

Comment: `c('red','blue',[species])` is not valid syntax, what did you really use?

Comment: I copied and pasted it directly from my code.  I deleted [species] and got blue and red points.....but they didn't match my data.